# Screen Forced Away from Dashboard

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, dashboard-widget, dashboard

I have this issue on my **Macbook Air** that happens often if I select a gadget on the dashboard. I get forced away from the dashboard to the Desktop. I noticed if I previously selected one gadget and I select a different gadget it will do this. For example:

1. I use the dictionary gadget
2. Move away from dashboard to do something else
3. Then go to the dashboard again to use a calculator
4. Forced away from dashboard

Is this a software problem or is it normal? If it is normal, can I stop this from happening in "system preferences"?

Version **10.7.5**

Comment: And this is not just an accidental swipe back to the Desktop with four fingers on the Trackpad? I cannot reproduce this behavior.

Comment: No, I use three fingers to swipe between the desktop and dashboard but click on the gadgets with a mouse. After swiping I do not touch the trackpad at all. Only the mouse. I am not sure about what triggers this to happen because sometimes this issue does not occur and only happens when least expected.

Comment: What sort of mouse? Two finger swipes can bring you to the Desktop with Magic Mouse.

Comment: It is made by a brand called Tuscani and I think the kind of mouse is supposed to be HD-M324s.

http://imgur.com/DPbpr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my software on my Mac and this problem has stopped. Thank you all for helping me with this issue.